# Analysis tool for customers

Tags: jquery, charts, ruby-on-rails-3.1, analytics

We are trying to enable customers (users who are registered to our web site) to view data on their dashboard. Data would be collected from our database and displayed via a graph / chart.

As owners and admins of the site, we are using Chart Beat and Google Analytics to analyze traffic. However, we would like to share this kind of information (traffic, charts, etc) that we are seeing to our customers.

We don't want to show site-wide information. Only traffic information pertaining to the customers's page (i.e. his profile page, his photo's, his comments, etc).

Is there a tool (API service) that we can use for this? Or will we have to use chart library such as Google Charts, Protovis, Gruff etc and plot our own?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand everything correctly.

Using google analytics you can capture specific domain information, and further mark certain events/actions specifically under that domain For example add, delete or update, you have that flexibility.

Since you don't want to share site wide statistics, you need to pull specific events from what google analytics gathers via their api, but I am not too familiar with their api but I believe that it should be supported.

Since google analytics captures everything, you may want to show only those specific actions via the api and fetch the data and plot it as charts. It will save you some level of code. You would need an intermediate level of transformation to transform the data from google analytics and plot it as charts / show it as data.